# Cannot set property 'onclick' of null (I have already added id)

Tags: javascript

I have already added id in HTML for JS, but when I open the website, it still displays an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.onclick = function() {
    var arrays = new Array();
    var items = document.getElementsByName("check");
    for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
        if(items[i].checked) {
            arrays.push(items[i].value);`enter code here`
        }
    }
    alert("numbers checked:" + arrays.length);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="check" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="check"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="check" checked/>
<input type="button" value="numbers you have checked" id="btn"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move your script to bottom. You are requesting an element before it is rendered

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ragesh @Rayon! It works fine now.

Comment: OMG sorry... Thank you again! @ Rajesh :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="check" checked/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="check" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="check" checked/>
    <input type="button" value="numbers you have checked" id="btn" />

    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        btn.onclick = function () {
            var arrays = new Array();
            var items = document.getElementsByName("check");
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if (items[i].checked) {
                    arrays.push(items[i].value);
                }
            }
            alert("numbers checked:" + arrays.length);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please explain why this will help. you are answering for readers

Comment: Thanks, now I understand to move the scripts after HTML so that requests can be called after the elements are rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an input, use a button. and call the function as below:

```
<button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">
```

Comment: If I change the HTML part into this, then how should I make changes for the JS part?